# Using Speech Recognition Engine to search

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I'm trying to use Microsoft Speech Recognition Engine to perform a search. I can get it to recognise terms in my Grammar, but I can't get the words after the search term. I'm trying to use the wildcard entry for this, but all I get back is '...'. Is this the right way to do it, or am I misunderstanding what the wildcard is for?

I've mainly been testing it using the emulator, but have done a few tests with actual speaking.

```
private void BeginListening()
    {
        this._recognitionEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"));
        this._recognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        this._recognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized += _recognitionEngine_SpeechRecognized;

        GrammarBuilder wakeWord = new GrammarBuilder("Bob");
        GrammarBuilder find = new GrammarBuilder("find");

        GrammarBuilder wildcard = new GrammarBuilder();
        wildcard.AppendWildcard();

        SemanticResultKey wildcardKey = new SemanticResultKey("SearchTerm", wildcard);
        GrammarBuilder gb = wildcardKey.ToGrammarBuilder();

        find.Append(wildcardKey);
        wakeWord.Append(find);

        Grammar grammar = new Grammar(wakeWord);
        grammar.Name = "Search";

        this._recognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(grammar);
        this._recognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync();
    }
```